# What does "racking in cash" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does it mean to "rack in some serious cash"? 
Does it mean to make money quickly and making loads of cash?

Comment: You probably have misheard  or misread 'raking in cash' meaning you are earning cash like you are raking leaves in quantity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes. It means making a lot of money fast.**

[Rake in](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rake+in) means

> *Fig.* to take in a lot of something, usually money.
>
> *"Our candidate will rake votes in by the thousand."*
>
> *"They were raking in money by the bushel."*

[Rack up](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rack+up) means

> *Fig.* to accumulate something; to collect or acquire something.
>
> *"They all racked a lot of profits up."*
>
> *"We racked up twenty points in the game last Saturday."*

**What you heard is probably a mix of these two.**

Also, [Serious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/serious) means

> *Informal* Of considerable size or scope; substantial
>
> *"a serious amount of money."*

Definitions from The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

To [rake in](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rake-sth-in?q=rake+in) means:

> to earn or get a large amount of money: '*He rakes in over $200,000 a year*.'

"Rake in some serious cash" - Making a lot of money quickly and steadily.

She's really [raking it in](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rake-sth-in?q=rake+in) (= making a lot of money).

To [rack something up](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rack-sth-up?q=rack+up) means:

> to gradually get more points, profits, etc.: '*He has racked up 450 points in three months.*'

[Cambridge Online Dictionary]